# replace div content using ajax and jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I try following code to replace div content but its not working what i am doing wrong?

```
function MakeRequest()
{
    $("#page_num li").click(function() {
       var id=(this.id); 
       alert(id);
        $.ajax({
        url : 'display.php',
        data:{"id":id},
        type: 'GET',

        success: function(data){
            $('#ResponseDiv').html(data);
        }
    });
});
}
```

//list to get value

```
<ul id="page_num">
              <li id="5"  onclick='MakeRequest();' ><a href="#">5</a></li>
              <li id="10"  onclick='MakeRequest();' ><a href="#">10</a></li>
               <li id="15"  onclick='MakeRequest();' ><a href="#">15</a></li>
           </ul>
```

//div to replace

```
<div id='ResponseDiv'>
        This is a div to hold the response.
</div>
```

//my display.php

```
<?php 
   echo "This is a php response to your request!!!!!!";
?>
```

EDIT:
how can i check its going or not to my display.php.
i have try solution but not get success.

Comment: Why you have defined onclick='MakeRequest();' and also jquery click event for it.

Answer (score 10):

Your code has a function which defines an onclick action and doesn't make the call itself.  I bet if you double clicked the link it would work, but you should do it like this:

```
function MakeRequest(id)
{
    $.ajax({
        url : 'display.php',
        data:{"id":id},
        type: 'GET',

        success: function(data){
            $('#ResponseDiv').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Finally, change the call to this:

```
onclick='MakeRequest(5);'
```

OR  just do this, which binds the li element to the click function and no "onclick" is necessary:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#page_num li").click(function() {
       var id=$(this).attr(id);
        $.ajax({
        url : 'display.php',
        data:{"id":id},
        success: function(data){
            $('#ResponseDiv').html(data);
        }
    });
});
});
```

Comment: what is point of `onclick='MakeRequest(5);'` if there is an `id` in the element

Comment: @ArashMilani which is why I would just do the second example and bind directly instead of making the call in the onclick method.

Comment: I think We better provide much pragmatic answers than just trying to do the things the way something has been asked.

Comment: how can i check its going or not to my display.php. i have try solution but not get success.i am trying to use makerequest fuction because i have another list on which will use same function.

Comment: you can use `firebug` in firefox or `developer tools` in `chrome` to watch for ajax requests. you can also use `console.info(var)` as a handy tool to inspect variables.

Answer (score 3):

remove `MakeRequest()` function just try using `$("#page_num li").click` otherwise it will call function twice

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#page_num li").click(function() {
      var id=(this.id); 
      $.ajax({
         url : 'display.php',
         data:{"id":id},
         type: 'GET',
         success: function(data){
            $('#ResponseDiv').html(data);
         }
      });
   });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You have onclick events binded to that function called `MakeRequest` then in that function you  again bind the `li`s to a click event.

You better take this approach:

```
$(function(){
    $("#page_num li").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
        url : 'display.php',
        data:{id: $(this).attr('id')},
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data){
            $('#ResponseDiv').html(data);
        }
    }
});
```

and get rid of inline `onclick` events.

Answer (score -1):

move the onclick event to the  tag so that:

`<a href="#" onclick='MakeRequest();>`