# add class to ajax trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've created a simple ajax loading content which works but I'm trying to change the class 'active' (it adds a border-bottom to let the user know which menu they are looking at) depending on which target has been clicked. I've attempted using jquery but to no avail. If someone could help or point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

This is my attempt:

```
     $(document).on('click', '.menu-tabs li a', function () {
      $('.active').removeClass('active');
      $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="menu-tabs" id="menu-tabs">
  <ul>
   <li class="active"><a href="#" data-target="food">FOOD</a></li>
   <li class=""><a href="#" data-target="desserts">DESSERTS</a></li>
   <li class=""><a href="#" data-target="drinks">DRINKS</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>

 <article class="menu-container" id="menu-container">
   <?php include('food.php'); ?>
  </article>
```

AJAX:

```
var trigger = $('#menu-tabs ul li a'),
    container = `$('#menu-container');

trigger.on('click', function () {

    var $this = $(this),
        target = $this.data('target');

    container.load(target + '.php');

    return false;
});`
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code section. Taken mostly from your own code. Just added the CSS for checking and it seems to work for me. At-least the navigation is changing "active" class on click.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.menu-tabs li a', function() {
  $('.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).parent().addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active{
  background:green;  
}
.active a{
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-tabs" id="menu-tabs">
  <ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="#" data-target="food">FOOD</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#" data-target="desserts">DESSERTS</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#" data-target="drinks">DRINKS</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<article class="menu-container" id="menu-container">
  <?php include('food.php'); ?>
</article>
```

Comment: For some reason I can't get it to work (I copied your code in case I was missing something) , I'm new to ajax so I might be initializing the code wrong??                  `$(document).ready(function () {` `});`

Comment: Are you getting any error message? Please check your browser's console to find out anything related. If there are any error messages please share the same.

Comment: There are no error messages. The jquery works when i comment out my ajax code but when I add it back in it completely ignores it. Is there a way to combine the two?

Comment: If you want to replace the page content using ajax, a very good example is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13832911/replace-div-content-using-ajax-and-jquery#answer-13832977)