# Mobile Redirect using Resolution in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, asp.net, .htaccess

I have 2 page

> index.php (For Desktop)

and

> indexm.php (For Mobile)

I want to redirect it with detection of **screen resolution size**.

I'm trying this code

```
<?php 
  if (screen.width <= 720) {
      include "indexm.php";
  } else {
      include "index.php";
  }
?>
```

But both the code is not working, Please help me with PHP Code to make it work.

**Note : I'm not looking Header Location**

`header('Location: indexm.php');`

Comment: This won't work in php, because php is a serverside script language. You have to this in javascript.

Comment: Is php has `screen.width` prop?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1504526/5907133

Comment: No because as I said php is a serverside scirpt language and has no information about the screen size of the user.

Comment: @Fabian Then how can i make index page redirection with mobile detection using PHP?

Comment: Have a look at Mikes link. You have to this in javascript.

Comment: @Fabian checking that but i am not expert in JS.

Comment: Try something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/16172930/5947371 or google (php include file screen resolution) around you will find tons of articles on the web about this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [include php file only at certain screen resolutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16172806/include-php-file-only-at-certain-screen-resolutions)

Comment: @Fabian Is there any alternative to PHP Include in JS? because PHP include is different then redirect?

Comment: In js you have `document.location = "indexm.php"` which acts like a redirect.

Comment: @Fabian i know how to do in JS but this will make redirect like `PHP Header Location` but i need like `PHP Include` which dont redirect URL

Comment: You can do a ajax get request to `indexm.php` and replace its content like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13832977/5947371

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since php is a server side language, it is not possible to detect screen resolution using php. You will have to use client side scripting to achieve the desired output.

Try the below javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(screen.width <= 720) 
    {
        location.href = "indexm.php"; // redirection
    }
    else
    {
        location.href = "index.php"; // redirection
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

this may solve your problem:

[try this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/redirect-mobile-devices/)

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

if (screen.width <= 720) {
document.location = "mobile.html";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This Works!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (screen.width <= 720) {
        window.location = "indexm.php";
    } else {
        window.location = "index.php";
    }
</script>
```